# "lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression" with Unicode element names

Tags: python, xpath, unicode, lxml

lxml nicely supports Unicode element names, as they are valid according to XML specification. But using Unicode in XPath produces an error:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> e = lxml.etree.fromstring('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><элемент>текст</элемент>'.encode('utf-8'))
>>> e.xpath('/элемент/text()')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1509, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:50702)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 318, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:145954)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 238, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144962)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 224, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144817)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

Is it an lxml limitation? I couldn't find it in docs, but maybe I missed it.

And can someone explain the reason behind this?

---

**Update:** Problem only reproduces if second character of XPath is Cyrillic. It works fine with:

- relative paths like `//элемент`
- paths with first English letter, like `//qлемент`
- `/./элемент` instead of `/элемент` (they are equivalent)

Moreover, it appears to be `libxml2` problem, not just `lxml` problem.

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/элемент/text()" test.xml 
Invalid expression: /элемент/text()
compilation error: element with-param
XSLT-with-param: Failed to compile select expression '/элемент/text()'
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/./элемент/text()" test.xml 
текст
```

I gave up on this problem and resorted to `/./` for absolute XPath with Cyrillic tags.

Comment: Python 2 or 3?  If Python 2, you probably need to pass a Unicode string to `xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is missing a `/` if referring to the root node:

```
>>> e.xpath('//элемент/text()')
['текст']
```

Or two dots `..` if referring to a relative parent node:

```
>>> e.xpath('../элемент/text()')
['текст']
```

Comment: Not the case. Problem reproduces only if second character of XPath is Cyrillic. Works fine with English tags or with relative paths as in your examples.